# Polymer - Disabling Transitions?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have problems disabling transition effects in Polymer (1.0).

Essentially, I want to disable `.transition > #drawe`r and `.transition > #main` that both come with

```
{
transition: -webkit-transform ease-in-out 0.3s, width ease-in-out 0.3s;
transition: transform ease-in-out 0.3s, width ease-in-out 0.3s;
}
```

None of these works:

```
.transition > #drawer {
transition:none!important;
}

.transition > #main {
transition:none!important;
}

.right-drawer.transition > #main {
transition:none!important;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is `#drawer` and `#main`?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about paper-drawer-panel 

<strike>then you can try to add this to the `<head>` tag of your entry page:</strike>

```
<style is="custom-style">
  :root {
    --paper-drawer-panel-scrim: {
      transition: none;
    }
  }
</style>
```

`#scrim` is the only element that supports to configure transition from the outside. You'd need to create a bug report or feature request at https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-drawer-panel to support that.

As workaround you could try

```
* /deep/ paper-drawer /deep/ .transition > #drawer {
transition:none;
}

* /deep/ paper-drawer /deep/ .transition > #main {
transition:none;
}

* /deep/ paper-drawer /deep/ .right-drawer.transition > #main {
transition:none;
}
```

but `/deep/` is deprecated and going to be removed eventually.